# mongoDB 3.2: Error when adding shards as part of batch script step

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing a batch script to setup a local mongodb environment for a project. Here are just the mongo shell scripts that are included in the batch file:

```
.\mongod.exe --port 10001 --dbpath C:\mongodb\data1 --replSet test1 --shardsvr
.\mongod.exe --port 10002 --dbpath C:\mongodb\data2 --replSet test2 --shardsvr
.\mongod.exe --port 27019 --dbpath C:\mongodb\config --replSet config --configsvr

.\mongo.exe --port 10001 --eval 'rs.initiate(); c=rs.conf(); c.members[0].host="localhost:10001"; rs.reconfig(c); quit();'
.\mongo.exe --port 10002 --eval 'rs.initiate(); c=rs.conf(); c.members[0].host="localhost:10002"; rs.reconfig(c); quit();'
.\mongo.exe --port 27019 --eval 'rs.initiate(); c=rs.conf(); c.members[0].host="localhost:27019"; rs.reconfig(c); quit();'

.\mongos.exe --configdb 'localhost:27019'

.\mongo.exe --eval 'sh.addShard("test1/localhost:10001"); (sh.addShard("test2/localhost:10002"); sh.enableSharding("Test"); quit();'
```

Everything runs fine except the last line where I get these errors when I do printjson:

> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.20
>   connecting to: test
>   {
>           "ok" : 0,
>           "errmsg" : "in seed list test1/localhost:10001, host localhost:10001 does not belong to replica set test1; found { hosts: [ \"moz:10001\" ], setName: \"test1\", setVersion: 1, ismaster: true, secondary: false, primary: \"moz:10001\", me: \"moz:10001\", electionId: ObjectId('7fffffff0000000000000001'), maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216, maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000, maxWriteBatchSize: 1000, localTime: new Date(1528834294036), maxWireVersion: 4, minWireVersion: 0, ok: 1.0 }",
>           "code" : 96
>   }
>
> {
>           "ok" : 0,
>           "errmsg" : "in seed list test2/localhost:10002, host localhost:10002 does not belong to replica set test2; found { hosts: [ \"moz:10002\" ], setName: \"test2\", setVersion: 1, ismaster: true, secondary: false, primary: \"moz:10002\", me: \"moz:10002\", electionId: ObjectId('7fffffff0000000000000001'), maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216, maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000, maxWriteBatchSize: 1000, localTime: new Date(1528834295075), maxWireVersion: 4, minWireVersion: 0, ok: 1.0 }",
>           "code" : 96
>   }
>
> { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "No shards found", "code" : 70 }

Here's a copy of the rs.status from each port:

> {
>           "set" : "test1",
>           "date" : ISODate("2018-06-12T20:11:30.110Z"),
>           "myState" : 1,
>           "term" : NumberLong(1),
>           "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
>           "members" : [
>                   {
>                           "_id" : 0,
>                           "name" : "moz:10001",
>                           "health" : 1,
>                           "state" : 1,
>                           "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
>                           "uptime" : 6,
>                           "optime" : {
>                                   "ts" : Timestamp(1528834287, 1),
>                                   "t" : NumberLong(1)
>                           },
>                           "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-06-12T20:11:27Z"),
>                           "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
>                           "electionTime" : Timestamp(1528834286, 2),
>                           "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-06-12T20:11:26Z"),
>                           "configVersion" : 1,
>                           "self" : true
>                   }
>           ],
>           "ok" : 1
>   }
>
> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.20
>   connecting to: 127.0.0.1:10002/test
>   {
>           "set" : "test2",
>           "date" : ISODate("2018-06-12T20:11:30.285Z"),
>           "myState" : 1,
>           "term" : NumberLong(1),
>           "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
>           "members" : [
>                   {
>                           "_id" : 0,
>                           "name" : "moz:10002",
>                           "health" : 1,
>                           "state" : 1,
>                           "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
>                           "uptime" : 6,
>                           "optime" : {
>                                   "ts" : Timestamp(1528834287, 1),
>                                   "t" : NumberLong(1)
>                           },
>                           "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-06-12T20:11:27Z"),
>                           "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
>                           "electionTime" : Timestamp(1528834286, 2),
>                           "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-06-12T20:11:26Z"),
>                           "configVersion" : 1,
>                           "self" : true
>                   }
>           ],
>           "ok" : 1
>   }
>
> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.20
>   connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27019/test
>   {
>           "set" : "config",
>           "date" : ISODate("2018-06-12T20:11:30.406Z"),
>           "myState" : 1,
>           "term" : NumberLong(1),
>           "configsvr" : true,
>           "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
>           "members" : [
>                   {
>                           "_id" : 0,
>                           "name" : "moz:27019",
>                           "health" : 1,
>                           "state" : 1,
>                           "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
>                           "uptime" : 5,
>                           "optime" : {
>                                   "ts" : Timestamp(1528834287, 1),
>                                   "t" : NumberLong(1)
>                           },
>                           "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-06-12T20:11:27Z"),
>                           "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
>                           "electionTime" : Timestamp(1528834286, 2),
>                           "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-06-12T20:11:26Z"),
>                           "configVersion" : 1,
>                           "self" : true
>                   }
>           ],
>           "ok" : 1
>   }